# VS Code won't launch python project, returns error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

VS Code won't launch python project, returns error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
```

I've uninstalled pygame, updated pygame and python, check pygame status and I can launch the test game from the website, I was able to launch my project then it stopped working and I keep getting this error after I merged some changes from my repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like just an environment problem. Could you check which python interpreter you are using, which pip you are using, which environment the pip has been installed into?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked on my desktop and hopefully it will fix it on my laptop also.

Comment: @Fullsailer If it's helpful, could you please upvote and accept this answer? thanks and have a good day : ).

Comment: No problem, thanks again Steven-MSFT